# Forcing scipy.optimize.minimize to take the maximum number of iteration steps

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize` with `method="L-BFGS-B"` to numerically minimize a cost function over a set of parameters. I have set `maxiter` manually in the parameters, but the optimizer terminates early when it meets method-specific criteria (according to `ftol` and `gtol`).

I would like to force the optimizer to take the maximum number of steps (`maxiter`) for the purposes of comparing different systems/cost functions - that is, I want to entirely switch off the early termination conditions. I have looked through the documentation and can't seem to find a way to do this. I've tried setting `ftol=0` and `gtol=0`, or at least setting them to be extremely small values, and neither of these seem to stop the early termination. How would I go about forcing it to take the maximum number of allowed steps?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At least in theory, setting `ftol=0.0` and `gtol=0.0` should be a reasonable way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/af3e73fa73b130f104d442596794f4ced37739f1/scipy/optimize/_optimize.py#L1245), one finds down in the working bits of `_minimize_bfgs` the following snippet:

```
    while (gnorm > gtol) and (k < maxiter):
    pk = -np.dot(Hk, gfk)
    try:
        alpha_k, fc, gc, old_fval, old_old_fval, gfkp1 = \
                 _line_search_wolfe12(f, myfprime, xk, pk, gfk,
                                      old_fval, old_old_fval, amin=1e-100, amax=1e100)
    except _LineSearchError:
        # Line search failed to find a better solution.
        warnflag = 2
        break
```

This is the big loop to do the minimization, and you see the `gtol` and `maxiter` that you passed in.

BUT - if the line search does not find a better solution, the routine breaks out of the `while` regardless of either the tolerance or number of iterations you have specified.

Your best solution would be to create a customized version that does not break out of the while loop. I'm not sure what that would actually accomplish for you, since the answer won't get any better, but that is up to you.